# php array not excepting index values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looping through a mysql recordset and saving image names to an php array, each mysql image row has a corresponding display order value that I want to use for the array index values. Here's my code:

```
if (!is_null($productRow['image_name'])) {
    $imgIndex = (int)$productRow['imgIndex'];
    $imgName = $productRow['image_name'];
    if (!in_array(($imgIndex.'-'.$imgName), $prodGalleryImgs)) {
        $prodGalleryImgs[$imgIndex] = $imgIndex.'-'.$imgName;
    }
}

print_r(array_values($prodGalleryImgs));
```

outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => 1-1407_15.jpg [1] => 3-1408_15.jpg [2] => 2-1409_15.jpg )
```

the values before the dashes (1, 3, 2) are correct and what I want to set as indexes

```
print_r(array_keys($prodGalleryImgs));
```

outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 2 )
```

So, I'm trying to set the indexes but instead I appear to be setting key values. I thought I understood arrays, obviously not.

Any help guidance would be gratefully received.

Comment: You are doing it right, I just don't understand why you use `array_values()` when you dump the results; that removes the original indices right before you display them.

Comment: And __now__ `print_r($prodGalleryImgs);`

Comment: What is the difference between the result of print_r(array_keys($prodGalleryImgs)); and what you expected? To me it seems identical